# What accounts for the behavior of the Benning/Thing when he moans just before they incinerate him?

Tags: the-thing-1982

Benning is the bearded, bald guy who is outside and someone says, It isn't Benning and we see that his hands have transformed. Then the Benning/Thing turns towards the group and moans/howls in clearly alien fashion.

He makes no attempt to save himself, simply by **not transforming**, seeming to accept that he is going to be destroyed.

What really is the point of the strange sound it produces? Is it possible that this is how humans, not yet completely transformed, behave? Like, the human part of him wants to communicate but the alien is preventing thing or perhaps during the transition period, the nervous system is incompletely duplicated so that normal speech is not even possible?